# How to add or use check box on SMOF in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I have used Slightly Modded Options Framework for my theme option. I want to make my menu bar show/hide in my theme. I want to use check box or switch to on/off the menubar. I have already pest code on smof function.

```
$of_options[] = array(  "name"      => "Primary Menu Enabled?",
                    "desc"      => "Please, use the menus panel to manage and organize menu items for the primary menu.",
                    "id"        => "menu_primary_enable",
                    "std"       => 1,
                    "type"      => "checkbox"
            );
```

And there is a option appear in my theme options. This is my menubar code.

```
      <?php 
if (function_exists('wp_nav_menu')) {
wp_nav_menu( array( 
    'theme_location' => 'menu-primary', 
    'container_class' => 'menu-primary-container',
    'items_wrap'      => '<ul class="menus menu-primary sub-menu sf-js-enabled">%3$s</ul>', 
    'fallback_cb' => 'cdb_default_menu'));
            }
            else {
                cdb_default_menu();
            } 

    ?>
```

Now which code I use there for show/hide menubar or theme options functional?

Answer (score 0):

I just find out an way. I have used this code:

```
<?php global $data; ?>
<?php if($data['your_option_id']): ?>
<......Something here.....>
<?php endif; ?>
```

The menubar code is like this

```
<?php global $data; ?>
<?php if($data['menu_primary_enable']): ?>

<?php 
if (function_exists('wp_nav_menu')) {
wp_nav_menu( array( 
    'theme_location' => 'menu-primary', 
    'container_class' => 'menu-primary-container',
    'items_wrap'      => '<ul class="menus menu-primary sub-menu sf-js-enabled">%3$s</ul>', 
    'fallback_cb' => 'cdb_default_menu'));
            }
            else {
                cdb_default_menu();
            } 

    ?>

<?php endif; ?>
```

And this is working fine.